# Movement through diagonal blocking enemies

Tags: dnd-4e, movement

[image: Moving through enemies]

In the above situation, it is unclear to me whether - ignoring opportunity attacks - it is possible to move to the bottom right corner from the centre square. A player wanted to do that in the game I was running on Sunday and I told him the creatures were blocking his path, but second guessed myself afterward as the space is an open, adjacent one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no reason that they shouldn't be able to do this.

The *only* rule for not being able to move diagonal is when a wall or other object extends to the corner of the square that you want to move into in a way that would block your path. If the near corner of the square you want to move past on the diagonal is not filled in (by a wall or other obstruction), you can safely move past it on the diagonal.

Comment: Okay, I kind of thought that it would be akin to moving through the middle of two creatures standing in a straight line, but on the diagonal. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Also, a square is 5ft. So unless the creature is 5 feet wide, its not filling its entire square.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this — usually.

The rule for diagonal movement is found on the top right of PHB p283:

> Moving diagonally works the same as other movement, except you can’t cross the corner of a wall or another obstacle that fills the corner between the square you’re in and the square you want to move to. You can move diagonally past most creatures, since they don’t completely fill their squares.

As you'll notice, you get leeway for moving past enemies — unless they somehow fill their squares so effectively they block off the corners. You won't run into this problem with a bunch of orcs, but you *could* find that you can't move diagonally past two big Gelatinous Cubes. Or two enormously overweight orcs, possibly.